# SailsJS - Create New Record with a custom ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

in SailsJS, when you create a new record, for example creating a new user, SailsJS will generate a random ID for that record. In the project I'm working on, I would like to use a current ID that was generated before instead letting sailsjs generate for me.

The reason for that is I'm trying to make 2 instances of sailsjs in sync with each other, and the IDs of the records has to match. so when i import data from one sailsjs to another i want to make sure that everything is exactly the same. I don't have any problem with the regular data, such as for example name, address, email. But when it comes to IDs sails refuse to create a record with a given Id.

Note that I'm using MongoDB, which generates ID such as `"5420873b5b9338143ac15c09"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

basically in your model, you have to add  `autoPK:false` 
But if you try to run sailsjs now you will get an error

```
Error: Trying to create an association on a model that doesn't have a Primary Key.
```

To fix that, you need to specify a different primary key for your table, in my case the user table. for example you can set the SSN to be the primary key.

```
ssn: {
       type: "string",
       primaryKey: true
     }
```

But notice now if you try to hit sailsjs with the old ID that will not work since the new PK now is different.

```
Will not work : localhost:1337/user/id 
Will work: localhost:1337/user/ssn
```

Comment: The part about `autoPK: false` is spot on, but you don't need to nominate a different attribute to be your primary key.  You can just explicitly declare an attribute called `id` and set it up as you have with `ssn` in your example, i.e. a string field with `primaryKey: true`

Comment: @sgress454 that is exactly what i ended up doing. Thanks!